# jQuery - sending POST to localhost network app (Hue Emulator)

Tags: javascript, jquery, localhost, philips-hue

I am trying to send a HTTP POST with JSON via jQuery to a local network app (Hue Emulator: http://steveyo.github.io/Hue-Emulator/) with this code:

```
$.post("http://localhost/api/newdeveloper/lights/6/state", "{\"on\": false}", function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

On the console of the app I see this response:

```
So, 12 Nov 2017 15:47:58   /api/newdeveloper/lights/6/state
So, 12 Nov 2017 15:47:58   {"on": false}
```

Which is the same as in this image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SteveyO/Hue-Emulator/master/screenshot.png

But I don't see any response and also the light bulb doesn't turn off visually in the emulator. Is there a problem with jQuery and sending localhost-POST requests? This is the result I see in Google Chrome:

[image]

With this approach:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST"
    , url: "http://localhost/api/newdeveloper/lights/6/state"
    , data: {
        "on": false
    } // or {"on": true} 
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I get: [image]

Answer (score 3):

use $.ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/api/newdeveloper/lights/6/state",
    data: {"on": false} // or {"on": true} 
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

return value log in console

Comment: add dataType: "json" to $.ajax after data option

Comment: according to [document](https://developers.meethue.com/documentation/lights-api) in this section **1.6. Set light state** set light state use _PUT_ method